# I am getting the error while running the python code for numpy.frombuffer a bytes-like object is required, not 'NoneType'

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, pyaudio

This code is running well in Windows (python version = 3.10.3) but when I run it in Linux (python version = 3.9.7) it is throwing the following error message:

```
import numpy as np

sound_buffer = np.frombuffer(in_data, dtype=np.float32)

TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'NoneType'
```

Here is the code snippet:

```
## Callback Thread ##

def callback(in_data, frame_count, time_info, status):
    global sound_data
    sound_buffer = np.frombuffer(in_data,np.uint8, dtype="float32")
    sound_data = np.append(sound_data, sound_buffer)
    if len(sound_data) >= 88200:
        audio_analysis_queue.put(sound_data)
        current_time = time.ctime(time.time())
        audio_analysis_queue.put(current_time)
        sound_data = np.zeros(0, dtype="float32")
    return sound_buffer, pyaudio.paContinue


pa = pyaudio.PyAudio()

stream = pa.open(format=AUDIO_FORMAT,
                 rate=AUDIO_RATE,
                 channels=NUMBER_OF_AUDIO_CHANNELS,
                 input_device_index=AUDIO_DEVICE_INDEX,
                 frames_per_buffer=NUMBER_OF_FRAMES_PER_BUFFER,
                 output=True,
                 stream_callback=callback)

# Starts the callback thread
stream.start_stream()

print("--- Listening to Audio Stream ---")
```

Comment: What is `in_data`.  The error tells us it's a `None`, not some sort "bytes-like` object (e.g. a string or file that yields strings.

Comment: Actually i am listening to the audio from the webcam in the linux system. so started some threads, i have updated the code. please help how to fix this ? @hpauji

Comment: i think in linux the pyAudio is not working. it is not capturing the sound.  can you know the pyAudio code to capture the sound ?